Why do i see blank page when i generate pdf file form JRXML?
I have two JRXML files: one for the main report and another for the sub-report. The sub-report accepts a list of items that need to be rendered.
The problem is that my PDF page is not fully occupied with the list of items, yet a blank page is still being rendered. To illustrate, I have given a background color to the frame that holds the actual content also shared the generated PDF file for reference.

I observed that if i remove just one element from the list that blank page disappers.

What is the problem with my design? I have gone through other discussions but couldn't find any solution.
My expectation is that if the content is small enough to fit on a single page, I should not get an extra blank page.
Main report jrxml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.15.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.15.0-dd49bfb94918336b8321d5507193f0169ead4e95  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="AlertDetail" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="902" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="0" uuid="22624e7a-b951-4fcf-aa52-00589b4cfd72">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="1460"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="itemSubreport" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
    <field name="itemList" class="java.util.List"/>

    <detail>
        <band height="600" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="40" y="0" width="400" height="600" backcolor="#008051" uuid="ef9c6da7-c069-43f2-ac08-a7c72cb6afc1"/>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="30" uuid="7b4df8a0-cd8d-4f80-ae17-8c0e13bb2737"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="16" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Item Details"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="30" width="400" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="bf41032a-1c01-4fef-b88a-83f68268494c">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"  uuid="c80c4ee9-db2d-40f3-9bdc-be44f6b6361f">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{itemList}.size()>0]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Item Counts"]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <subreport>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="20" width="400" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="5f527911-9c0d-4e1b-aecc-90809af04ba8">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{itemList}.size()>0]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource
                        ($F{itemList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{itemSubreport}]]></subreportExpression>
                    </subreport>
                </frame>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>

JRXML for subreport (itemSubreport):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.15.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.15.0-dd49bfb94918336b8321d5507193f0169ead4e95  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="JRPerson" pageWidth="300" pageHeight="40" whenNoDataType="NoPages" columnWidth="300" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="9ba2c91d-f99e-4b48-932c-f18a03a55821">
    <style name="Style1"/>
    <field name="rowLabel" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="totalCount" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="topPadding" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a7d9dbdb-bd67-4f01-a758-8bb9a510cfe0">
                    <property name="topPadding" value="5"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#D3D3D3"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Item"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="150" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="821fa6f3-192e-465a-a646-706402981be4">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#D3D3D3"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Total"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="f112eeb0-ef8e-4f2f-ac8a-e3b2c51a1d46">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#D3D3D3"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" markup="styled"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{rowLabel}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement x="150" y="0" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="5d9695d1-bc5e-4dbe-9824-06b3380475c2">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#D3D3D3"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" markup="styled"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{totalCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>


